# How to change textboxfor's input name when we are using multiple model in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using multiple model hence textboxfor's input name is different because of multiple model so parameters are always null.

I explain what I mean as you can see at below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.managers.person_name)
```

I have two tables which are "manager" and "mayor_assistance" and I call these models with my class. Everything is fine at this point. But when I used these models with the TextBoxFor input name is set " manager.person_name" but my table which name is manager has a person_name column hence  my parameters are always null as you can see html tag at the below

```
<input id="managers_person_name" name="managers.person_name" type="text" value="">
```

Then I have to changed tex box for input name with "new" tag, I get the same result

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.managers.person_name,new { @name="person_name" })
```

So how can I change TextBoxFor input name?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the answer.I want to share my solution who be faced with my problem.

TextBoxFor or something like EditBoxFor etc.. their names and ids are set by properties on the Model.Because of this you get parameter always Null!

The solution is very simple just use TextBox and put your column name as string

```
  <div class="editor-field ">
            @Html.TextBox("person_name")
             @Html.ValidationMessage("person_position")
        </div>
```